# jQuery and Wordpress: Dynamically loading posts and being able to bookmark

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, dynamic, load

I am making a wordpress theme, and I want it to be able to dynamically load posts using jquery's .load() function.  I already have the load functionality; however, upon reloading the page, the dynamically loaded post disappears.  I want the user to be able to bookmark a dynamically loaded post, and then for that post to still be there when the user reloads the page (or bookmarks it and opens the bookmark).  My question is: is there a bookmarking plugin that is compatible with wordpress and my scenario?

I've already tried http://tkyk.github.com/jquery-history-plugin/
and http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/docs/
and they both don't work for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you need a deep linking/history plugin. My choice library is [SWFAddress](http://www.asual.com/swfaddress/). It simply puts a query string after a hash tag that you are able to read and write to. All you have to change is instead of making a call from the click, you listen for a page change event dispatched from SWFAddress.

Comment: Thanks!  I looked around the rest of the site, and found http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/, which as I understand is basically the same thing, just with javascript instead of flash.  It should be exactly what I need.

Comment: SWFAddress is a standalone javascript version. If you use it with flash, you still use the javascript, it just has a flash wrapper. If you use it with ajax, you'd just be using the standalone version. The jQuery version is simply just a wrapper to make it easier for you. Its pretty awesome to use, just make sure you have history=true somewhere, so that the back buttons work flawlessly. Enjoy!